# React context API - can't update parent consumer from child provider

Tags: reactjs

I have the following two class components:

```
Class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = ({});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <GameContext.Consumer>
          {value => value.isInGame ? <Game /> : <h1>Not in game</h1>}
        </GameContext.Consumer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And the `Game` component inside App:

```
class Game extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = ({});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <GameContext.Provider value={{isInGame: false}}>
                    <Content/>
                </GameContext.Provider>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

So by default my `isInGame` defined in the `GameContext` is `true`. Then the app renders the `Game` component which is wrapped as a provider and it passes a value which never reaches the app - the consumer.

The context is properly imported and created with `React.createContext({isInGame: true})`.

Also tried to use static `contextType` in the App instead of wrapping it as a consumer but to no success. What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your have `<Game />` inside `<App />`. Default value in context = {} (React.createContext({})). So app never goes inside `<Game />` component.

Cause:

```
<GameContext.Consumer>
  {value => value.isInGame ? <Game /> : <h1>Not in game</h1>}
</GameContext.Consumer>
```

Comment: value.isInGame is undefined => never goes inside  ```<Game />```

Comment: Edited my post, the default value is isInGame: true and the Game component does get rendered.